# Why do Welch's t-test results differ from Welch's ANOVA post-hoc tests?

Tags: python, t-test, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, scipy

I have data on elevation between three different berry types in Python (`Raspberry`, `Sunberry`, `Cranberry`), here is the data:

```
     Elevation    Crop  site
0    6.38606      R     1
1    3.86458      R     2
2    3.52326      S     3
3    4.74866      R     4
4    4.84225      S     5
..   ...         ..     ..
163  5.01838      R     8
164  4.91557      S     9
165  5.05761      R     10
166  3.83972      R     11
167  3.83046      R     12
```

And some general statistics on the groups:

```
Mean:
R: 1.938
S: 4.419
C: 3.892

Std.dev:
R: 2.542
S: 2.046
C: 1.987

Number of obs
R: n = 11
S: n = 6
C: n = 5
```

I assume the mean elevation at which they grow are different, and I would like to test this. I know the variance and group sizes are different thus I choose for manually doing a Welch`s t-test for each group comparison. However, when I then utilised the ANOVA test from Welch to compare all three groups, I get different results. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import pingouin as pg

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/data.csv')

print(stats.ttest_ind(df[df['Crop'] == 'R'].Elevation.dropna(), df[df['Crop'] == 'S'].Elevation.dropna(), equal_var = False))
print(stats.ttest_ind(df[df['Crop'] == 'R'].Elevation.dropna(), df[df['Crop'] == 'C'].Elevation.dropna(), equal_var = False))
print(stats.ttest_ind(df[df['Crop'] == 'S'].Elevation.dropna(), df[df['Crop'] == 'C'].Elevation.dropna(), equal_var = False))

# Perform Welch ANOVA
welch_result = pg.welch_anova(data = df, dv = 'Elevation', between = 'Crop')

# Display Welch ANOVA results
print("Welch ANOVA Results:")
print(welch_result)

# Perform pairwise comparisons using Games-Howell test
tukey_results = stats.pairwise_tukey(data = df, dv = 'Elevation', between = 'Crop')

# Display pairwise comparisons
print("\nPairwise comparisons (Tukey test):")
print(tukey_results)
```

The results differ between the tests:

```
Welch`s t-tests
Ttest_indResult(statistic = -2.084,  pvalue = 0.06)
Ttest_indResult(statistic = -1.591,  pvalue = 0.14)
Ttest_indResult(statistic =  0.4319, pvalue = 0.68)

Welch`s ANOVA w. Tukey-Kramer
Pairwise comparisons (Tukey test):
   A  B  mean(A)   mean(B)    diff        se         T   p-tukey    hedges
0  C  R  3.89297  1.93853  1.95444  0.127238  1.536054  0.299653  0.771389
1  C  S  3.89297  4.41998  0.52701  0.138132 -0.381527  0.923255 -0.238423
2  R  S  1.93853  4.41998  2.48145  0.120228 -2.063948  0.127460 -0.987895

Welch`s ANOVA w. Games Howell
   A  B  mean(A)   mean(B) ...         T         df      pval    hedges
0  C  R  3.89297  1.93853  ...  1.591293  10.313845  0.292242  0.771389
1  C  S  3.89297  4.41998  ... -0.431931   8.735549  0.903374 -0.238423
2  R  S  1.93853  4.41998  ... -2.084965  12.385126  0.133544 -0.987895
```

Why does this happen?
And which to trust: the ANOVA from Welch over the manual pairwise comparison using Welch`s T-tests over and over again?
Cheers

Comment: Results of post-hoc multiple comparison tests like Tukey after ANOVA is not the same as 2-sample t-tests, no matter whether there is heterogeneity of variance or not for the t-tests. If you ran ANOVA, use Tukey, Scheffe, or the other test you used.  A statistics instructor will never tell you to use t-tests for multiple comparisons after ANOVA -- that's why Tukey and Scheffe tests exist.

Comment: These results don't seem all that different. The T statistics for ANOVA with Games-Howell comparisons are identical to the several T tests. The p values are larger, which is to be expected from a multiple comparisons method. I don't see a problem.